# How to update Label in a loop

Tags: java, swt

I have an app which fills a table with file names. I want to show the user the number of files found within the loop so there is a continual progress report.

```
DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream( Paths.get( sourcePath ));

for (Path sourceFile : stream)
{
    file = sourceFile.toFile();

    if (file.isFile())
    {
         filename = file.getName();

         sorted.put( filename , filename );

         fileCount++;

         if (fileCount % 100 == 0)
         {
             ivLabelFileCount.setText( "Found: " + fileCount ) );
             ivLabelFileCount.update();
         }
    } 
}
```

As it runs I get a file count display of 100, 200, 300, etc. However the file count display stops at about 1,100. After a short while I get a final count of 2,831. So the display of the count by hundreds stops at about 1,100 even though the loop is still executing.

How do I get the label to display until the loop if finished? It's as if SWT stops updating the display even though I am changing the label text. Almost as if it can't keep up with the text changes.

Comment: Needs more context.  Can you produce a [mcve] for us?

Comment: You can't use loops like that in the UI thread, it will just block until you return to the readAndDispatch loop.

Comment: You mean like `String sourcePath ="C:\somedir";` and `Label ivLabelFileCount - new Label(shell,SWT.RIGHT);`?

Comment: I don't care if it blocks. Overall the entire thing just takes a few seconds, and the user DID ask for the function, so...

Comment: By blocks I mean there is no guarantee anything on the UI will be updated including your control - as you are seeing. You need to do this in a background thread and use Display.syncExec to update the UI control

Comment: Ah, I see. It just seemed strange that I would get 10-11 display updates and then nothing.